# How do I print a binary tree “as a” tree?

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

I made a program that inserts values, sorts them using binary search, and outputs the sorted values. However, I also would like to use the function PrintTree() to print the tree. I can't think of any way to implement a functioning code in that function.
Here is my code up until now.

```
#ifndef b_h
#define b_h

#include <iostream>

class BSTNode
{
public:
    int Key;
    BSTNode * Left;
    BSTNode * Right;
    BSTNode * Parent;
    int Height;
};

class BST
{
private:
    BSTNode * root;
    BSTNode * insertKey(BSTNode * node, int newKey);
    void PrintTreeInOrder(BSTNode * node);
    BSTNode * hasKey(BSTNode * node, int searchKey);
 



public:
    BST();
    ~BST();
    void insertKey(int newKey);
    void PrintTreeInOrder();
    bool hasKey(int searchKey);
     void TreePrint();

};

#endif
```

The header file above.

```
#include "b.h"

BST::BST() : root(NULL)
{
}


BSTNode * BST::insertKey(BSTNode * node, int newKey)
{
   
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        node = new BSTNode;
        node->Key = newKey;
        node->Left = NULL;
        node->Right = NULL;
        node->Parent = NULL;
    }
  
    else if(node->Key < newKey)
    {
        node->Right = insertKey(node->Right, newKey);
        node->Right->Parent = node;
    }
  
    else
    {
        node->Left = insertKey(node->Left, newKey);
        node->Left->Parent = node;
    }

    return node;
}

void BST::insertKey(int newKey)
{
    root = insertKey(root, newKey);
}

void BST::PrintTreeInOrder(BSTNode * node)
{
    if(node == NULL)
        return;

   
    PrintTreeInOrder(node->Left);
    std::cout << node->Key << " ";

    PrintTreeInOrder(node->Right);
}

void BST::PrintTreeInOrder()
{
    PrintTreeInOrder(root);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

BSTNode * BST::hasKey(BSTNode * node, int key)
{
  
    if (node == NULL)
        return NULL;

    else if(node->Key == key)
        return node;
   
    else if(node->Key < key)
        return hasKey(node->Right, key);
   
    else
        return hasKey(node->Left, key);
}

bool BST::hasKey(int searchKey)
{
   
    BSTNode * result = hasKey(root, searchKey);

    return result == NULL ?
        false :
        true;
}
```

The cpp file above.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include "b.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Binary Search Tree" << endl;

    BST * tree = new BST;

    cout << "Enter the numbers to be stored (end with a letter): ";

    int value;
    int i = 0;
    vector <int> keys;
    
     
cin >> value;
    while (!cin.fail()){
    
    keys.push_back(value);
    cin >> value;
    i++;
   }
       cin.clear(); // reset failbit
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
   

    for(const int& key : keys){
        tree->insertKey(key);}

    int number;
    cout << "Which number do you want to look up? " <<endl;
    cin >> number;
   
    bool b = tree->hasKey(number);
    if(b){
        cout << number << " is in the tree: yes";}
    else{
        cout << number << " is in the tree: no";
    cout << endl;}
    
    cout << "The numbers in sorted order: ";
    tree->PrintTreeInOrder();

     tree->TreePrint();
   

    return 0;
}
```

And the main.

This program works and it sorts the vector using binary search and has a search-for-key function, however, I want to print the tree in the function PrintTree(); as follows for example;

```
       8
    3    10
 1    6     14
    4  7   13
```

Can anyone help?